# How do I return an image from code?

Tags: media

I'm converting some old Drupal 6 code. Some template files for custom content types use code similar to the following.

```
if (some_parameter) {
  header(/* Set the MIME type for the image type */);
  readfile($image_file_name);
  exit();
}
else {
  // return HTML markup.
}
```

This used to work, although it is very ugly.

With Drupal 7, it does not work anymore. I believe it applies some templates when I just need the raw image file output with the MIME type I set.

What is the way to properly do this in Drupal 7? I already have the image as a file, but that is done in code, so I could put the image file anywhere, maybe even in the database. However it's not a user-uploaded file.

Comment: It's different in 7 to 8, it would be better to focus on which one you actually need to implement this in. And it definitely won't work in a template, I'm surprised it did in D6 to be honest. The correct place to do this is in the menu callback (D7), or the Controller delivery method (D8)

Comment: So, the site has content types, and instead of rendering the content type, you want to display an image instead when visiting the node? That's a strange use case and I'm confused. One thing you could do is look at hook_page_alter() for Drupal 7, but that won't work for Drupal 8. It might be better to explain how this weird send an image instead of render the page content is intended to work?

Comment: I inherited this code from someone else. We're not using Drupal as it should be used at all. I agree completely that this is an ugly hack, which has worked so far. To see what happens with D7 I changed the content type to text/plain, and then I see that D7 applies the theme as I suspected. So I get some HTML, then the binary data. I'll try the menu callback method that @clive suggested.

Comment: This works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18384278/1836964. It's using a menu callback as @clive suggested. And using ..._deliver_page hook.

Comment: The use case could be extended to any binary file, such as delivering a PDF.